# make call to ORCID public api using node js

Tags: node.js, orcid

I am very new in ORCID and studied it's documentation from http://orcid.org/. But i have to call some of it's public api from nodejs code.I have searched a lot but not getting anything related to this. Please anyone help me.
Thanks

Comment: Try looking here for example code http://members.orcid.org/api/code-examples - there is also code on github and useful information elsewhere in the members center

Answer (score 1):

The [ORCID public v2.0 API supports swagger](https://pub.orcid.org/v2.0/).  Although not yet complete at the time of writing (it's missing bio information), the API allows querying of activities listed on an ORCID record.  As it supports swagger, you can use [swagger-js](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js) to generate a client.

You can use it like this:

```
  var myORCID = "0000-0003-0902-4386";
  swagger = new SwaggerClient({
    url: "https://pub.orcid.org/resources/swagger.json",
    success: function() {
      swagger.apis["Public API v2.0"].viewActivities({orcid:myORCID},{responseContentType: 'application/json'}, function(data) {
        //do stuff with the JSON
      });
    }
  });
```

For more info and examples, read this [quickstart guide to ORCID with swagger](http://demeranville.com/getting-started-with-the-public-orcid-api-using-swagger-quickstart-guide/).

Comment: the link doesn't work any more and seems outdated